# How does the equation $y'=\frac{y^2}{1-xy}$ with $y(0)= 1$ satisfy the relation $y=e^{xy}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

My book says that the equation satisfies this relation, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Hint***

Consider $x'=\frac {dx}{dy}$

to get the classical form:

$$x'+ \frac x y= \frac 1 {y^2}$$

Multiply by y the equation :
$$(xy)'=\frac 1 y$$
Integrate:
$$xy=\int \frac {dy} y$$

$$xy=\ln(y)+K$$

$$y=Ke^{xy}$$

Use $y(0)=1$ to get the value of K

Comment: Thank you for answering. I finaly understand.

Comment: yw Chen ... ...........

Answer (score 2):

You can verify it easily by differentiating $$y=e^{xy}$$

So that $$y'=e^{xy}(y+xy')=y(y+xy')$$ and the result follows immediately

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani You may not, but I do.

Comment: You are correct. Now I got it right.